# Sharepoint, programmatically get user Permissions for Document Libraries

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I am using web services to get user permissions for document librarys in sharepoint. I tried using "GetPermissionCollection" but it only works when the user has Full control. If the user has any other permission i get 401 error.
Can someone please tell me a way to get the user permissions for document libraries.

Thanks and Regards,
Aakanksha

Comment: You should post info about sharepoint version and programming language, it would make it much easier to help you. Mayby something like that http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/ssahmed/spuserperm09192006044916AM/spuserperm.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a permissions issue rather than a programming issue.

SharePoint web services respect security... in other words, you can't do anything using the web services you don't have permission to do. Either...

1. Give the account you are using permission
2. Use a different account that has permission

Comment: Thanks Kit...

but actually i have an application where i wish to display all document libraries for which the current user has Write permissions. How can i get this information... GetLists doesnt return me anything about permissions... And as i told earlier "GetPermissionCollection" only returns me the permissions when the user has Full control as permissions....

Dont we have anything like "GetRolesAndPermissionsForCurrentUser" to get permissions for lists. I am using this to get the site level permissions for the current user... But this does not work for lists :( 

Please do help....

Comment: @Aakanksha: It looks like you made this comment into a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511320/sharepoint-web-services-how-to-get-permissions-for-a-document-library-for-the-cu Answer is posted there